# Problematic Lumia 1020 and 620

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-1020, nokia-lumia-620

I ran W10M build 10586.164 on my lumia 620. Did a hard reset , and restored from the backup that was made in 8.1. Had issues on the build like battery drain , used to lag and all , so I reverted back to 8.1 and now restored from the backup file that was created in 10586.164.

Now my 8.1 too had the same issues , battery drain , laggy nature etc. Tried a hard reset on 8.1 like a million times but still no results. Even tried flashing the phone , but no success.

I had a L1020 too which was on 8.1 only , restored from the backup made in 10586.164 (above ) and my 1020 is having the same issues.

Has some system file gone corrupt ? Even flashing the firmware isn't helping..

Did a lot of research on this topic..

Maybe emmc system repair might help ? 
I have a file named " LUMIA_620_RM-846_BIG_BOOT.mmc " which maybe able to reset the emmc file system but couldn't find any tool to flash this .mmc file.

A tool named as QPST ( Qualcomm product support tool ) does that but it detects my phone as in 'download' mode and it requires 'diagnostic' mode which has been removed from wp8.1.

Any help on this situation ?

Comment: How was the 8.1 running before recovering the backup?

Comment: @KolappanNathan  It was perfect before.. :( All my important data was there in that backup so I had to restore.. Didn't know it would create such a mess.. By the way I went to the Nokia care center , and they said it would cost Rs 8999 ( ~ $130 ) to fix my 1020.. :(

Comment: By data do you mean messages and contacts or anything else. If it is only messages, contacts and mms there is a workaround. If it is something else such as game data, etc... then I don't know the solution.

Comment: General device backup ( app settings etc ).

Comment: Oh. Okay. I don't know a workaround for this. Hopefully someone else may help you with this.